# SSL wildcard Certificate to Heroku

Tags: heroku, dns, ssl-certificate

I just recently added the SSL Endpoint add-on to my "example" app, and
updated my SSL Cert and Private Key from DNSimple to Heroku (according to this article:
http://ryan.mcgeary.org/2011/09/16/how-to-add-a-dnsimple-ssl-certificate-to-heroku/
) thanks to this command:

```
$ heroku certs:add STAR_example_com-bundle.pem STAR_example_com-private.key --app example
Adding SSL endpoint to example... done
example now served by oita-4417.herokussl.com
Certificate details:
    subject: /OU=Domain Control Validated/OU=EssentialSSL Wildcard/CN=*.example.com
    start date: 2012-07-28 02:00:00 CEST
    expire date: 2013-07-29 01:59:59 CEST
    common name(s): *.example.com, example.com
    issuer: /OU=Domain Control Validated/OU=EssentialSSL Wildcard/CN=*.example.com
    SSL certificate is verified by a root authority.
```

But now, when I try to access to my app with https://example.com (and sub-domains such as https://foo.example.com), I have a
warning (inside a big red page, using Chrome)...

How could I fix this? Maybe I have to wait some hours? Thanks!

Comment: Did you ever fix this.  If so, how?